# v-cloak does not work in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

There is a `div` in my page that for show the error message.When I refresh the page,it will appear for a while then it disappear. I added `v-cloak` but it doesn't work.

this is the code, `showErrorMsg` is false

```
<div v-cloak v-show="showErrorMsg" style="z-index:100" class="h5_tips tips_error">
  <a href="#" v-on:click="showErrorMsg = false" class="del"><i>&#xe906;</i></a>
  <p v-text="errorMsg"></p>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs - Hide vuejs syntax when page loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186831/vuejs-hide-vuejs-syntax-when-page-loading)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this problem by rewriting the CSS and adding a class in the CSS file

**CSS**:

```
[v-cloak] .v-cloak--hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div v-show="showErrorMsg" style="z-index:100" class="h5_tips tips_error v-cloak--hidden">
  <a href="#" v-on:click="showErrorMsg = false" class="del"><i>&#xe906;</i></a>
  <p v-text="errorMsg"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I still needed to have v-cloak as well but this gave the best result.

Comment: Useful gist which expands suggested solution https://gist.github.com/adamwathan/3584d1904e4f4c36096f

Answer (score 87):

Just include this code to your css file

```
[v-cloak] { display:none; }
```

https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak

Usage example:

```
<div class="xpto" v-cloak>
    Hello
</div>
```

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue
> instance finishes compilation. Combined with CSS rules such as
> [v-cloak] { display: none }, this directive can be used to hide
> un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready.

Comment: I would suggest adding this to the bottom of the CSS file. v-cloak is a regular CSS and can be overwritten. So, if it doesn't work for you, check if some other style is not forcing different display property. Alternatively, disable vue and see if the code is hidden. Vue will then make it visible.

Comment: This doesn't work if your `<div>` has `display: ...` set to something other than the default. In that case you may need `!important` as Pleymor's answer suggests.

Comment: Updated link is https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak

Answer (score 30):

I faced the same issue, and it was due to a conflicting `display` property on my `div`. To solve it, I used the `!important` flag on the `[v-cloak]` as:

```
[v-cloak] {
    display: none !important;
}

.my-class {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Vue.js - 2.3.4**, I added the **v-cloak** on the app container, adding this on the parent container, I find your not repeating the code keeping it **DRY**.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
 Anything inside gets the v-cloak
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
[v-cloak] {
 display:none;
}
```

**Codepen Example:**

- https://codepen.io/Frontend/pen/RjoKQm

Comment: Great suggestion. Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CDN to get Vue and using Bootstrap CSS then the reason might be you are loading the Bootstrap CSS in the bottom of the body tag, moving it back to the head tag worked for me. Make sure that you keep that vueJS file in the button as it is.

```
<HTML>
<head>
  All link and script tag here
</head>
<body> 
  <div id='app' v-cloak>
    {{ something }}
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a scenario where I've got a search form and below, the results with a `v-if` block, waiting for submit.

I changed the `v-if` to `v-show`, that seemed to help. I tried the `v-cloak--hidden` class but didn't work either (`v-cloak` is already styled to `display: none`). What *did* work apparently was to set the data results container display style to none and then when submitting the form (in the `processForm` method), setting the display to block and show all the results.

```
  processForm() {
      // reset page number on new search          
      document.getElementById("data-container").style.display="block"
      this.pageNumber = 1;
      this.remoteRequest();
  },
```

Without that change, on a full page refresh I could *still* see the moustaches coming up. Here the full HTML page, simplified.

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
      <main class="main-section">
        <form method="POST" class="p-4 text-center" @submit.prevent="processForm">
            <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">
               Find
            </button>
        </form>

        <!-- Results  -->
        <div id="data-container" class="container-fluid pt-2 pb-4" style="display:none">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                 <div id="recordsContainer" v-show="totalInScreen > 0">
                    <div class="card mt-5" v-for="(result, index) in results" :id="'itm-'+index" :key="result.id">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                             <h2 class="doctor-name">{{ result.doct_name }}</h2>
                             <h2 class="doctor-bio">Bio</h2>
                             <p>{{result.doct_bio}}</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </main>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately the above 2 answers didn't work for me as the problem was something else. Since this questions pops up #1 on Google, I thought I'd share my solution.

If you've defined a display css rule somewhere that's more specific, it will break the v-cloak functionality. However! Do not despair - simply copy this into your CSS file and it *will* work!

```
[v-cloak] .v-cloak--block {
  display: block!important;
}

[v-cloak] .v-cloak--inline {
  display: inline!important;
}

[v-cloak] .v-cloak--inlineBlock {
  display: inline-block!important;
}

[v-cloak] .v-cloak--hidden {
  display: none!important;
}

[v-cloak] .v-cloak--invisible {
  visibility: hidden!important;
}

.v-cloak--block,
.v-cloak--inline,
.v-cloak--inlineBlock {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: This and the other answers didn't work for me, because I was using v-cloak in combination with v-if. I needed to wrap all v-if blocks in a <div v-cloak> and then it worked as documented.