# How do I hide the VueJS syntax while the page is loading?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

maybe this is a trivial question.

so, when I run my vuejs application on browser with enables throttling download speed (sets to low connection). I got unfinished vue syntax output in browser.

[image: Vue js syntax appear in browser]

I know we can trick this out with showing **loading image** before entire page has loaded, but it's there any best solution to fix this?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

You can use the [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) directive, which will hide the Vue instance until the compilation finishes, if you combine it with the right CSS.

HTML:

```
<div v-cloak>{{ message }}</div>
```

CSS:

```
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

Comment: in api says : 
`[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
<div v-cloak>
  {{ message }}
</div>`

it means, I should add `v-cloak` attribute in every element that I I wish to hide ?

Comment: Just to the main `App` div should be fine

Comment: @Jeff  ah, I've just aware of it. well `v-cloak` seems a best answer. thanks @Gus !!

Comment: This works but man it's clunky. I was really hoping for something more elegant. +1 though

Comment: Seems like `v-cloak` should be the default and that if someone really wanted to show the `{{ }}` they should use  something like `v-uncloak`.

Comment: `display:none` on existing HTML, is a bad flag for SEO. I think it may be better to use some kind of overlay till page loads.

Comment: You can't add this to the Vue div, you have to add it to something inside the Vue div.

Comment: using css `[v-cloak] { visibility: hidden }` instead prevents layout updates after it is loaded.

Answer (score 46):

I attached the following codepen. You can see the difference with and without `v-cloak`.

```
<div id="js-app">
[regular]Hold it... <span>{{test}}</span><br/>
[cloak]Hold it... <span v-cloak>{{test}}</span>
</div>
```

---

http://codepen.io/gurghet/pen/PNLQwy

Comment: yeah I got it...
thanks, your codepen would be help for the new comers.

Comment: you still get the first {{test}} whilst vuejs is loading so its not a perfect answer

Comment: @twigg That's the point. The first one shows regular tag and the second shows cloaked tag using the `v-cloak` attribute.

Answer (score 41):

As suggested by others using [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) is proper solution. However as @ DelightedD0D mentioned it IS clunky. Simple solution is to add some CSS in the pseudo selector `::before` of `v-cloak` directive.

In your sass/less file something along the lines of

```
[v-cloak] > * { display:none; }
[v-cloak]::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url(/images/svg/loader.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Of course you'd need to provide a valid and accessible path to loader image. It will render something like.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

Using `v-cloak` directive you can hide un-compiled mustache bindings until vue instance is done compiling. You must use the CSS block to hide it until compiled.

**HTML:**

```
<div v-cloak>
  {{ vueVariable }}
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

This `<div>` will not be visible until the compilation is completed.

You can see this link [Hide elements during loading using `v-cloak`](http://vuetips.com/v-cloak-directive-hides-html-on-startup) for better understating.

Answer (score 8):

Don't include any vuejs syntax in the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Super app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your main JavaScript, you can:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

See the [vuetify webpack template](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack/tree/master/template) for reference.

Another solution is to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Super app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" is="App"></div>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
Vue.component("App", App);

const app = new Vue({});

window.addEventListener("load", async () => {    
  app.$mount("#app")
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Putting everything inside a `<template>` worked well for me.

The content is hidden until rendered by Vue.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <span class="name">{{ name.first }} {{ name.last }}</span>
  </template>
</div>
```

```js
/* index.js */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: { first: 'David', last: 'Davidovich'}
  }
});
```

Comment: that trick is good enough for my use case, thank you !

Answer (score 6):

```
**html**
<div v-cloak>{{ message }}</div>

**css**
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `<v-cloak>` to hide your Vue code before binding data to relevant places. It's actually located in a place on Vue documentation that anyone might miss it unless you search for it or read thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

You could move any rendering to a simple *wrapper* [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). The VueJS initialisation e.g. **new Vue(....)** shouldn’t contain any HTML apart from that single wrapper component.

Depending on setup you could even have `<app>Loading...</app>` where **app** is the wrapper component with any loading HTML or text in between which is then replaced on load.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can use `v-cloak`, I like use **spinkit**, is a great library with only CSS, check a simple example:

```js
var vm = null;
    setTimeout(function() {
     vm = new Vue({
         el: '#app',
        data: {
          msg: 'Is great, using: ',
          url: 'http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/'
         }
      });
     }, 3000);
```

```css
#app .sk-rotating-plane,
[v-cloak] > * { display:none }
body{
 background: #42b983;
 color: #35495e;
}
#app[v-cloak] .sk-rotating-plane {
 display:block;
 background-color: #35495e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit/master/css/spinkit.css">


<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <div class="sk-rotating-plane"></div>
    <h1>Vue with c-cloak</h1>
  <p>
    {{ msg }}
    <a :href='url'>{{ url }}</a>
  <p>
</div>
```

Link:
 - http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

Answer (score 0):

For those who use v-cloak in a view with multiple  Laravel Blade files and it's not working, try to use the v-cloak on the parent blade file rather than in any child blade file.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using `v-if` with a computed property that checks if my data is ready, like this:

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="shouldDisplay">
        {{ variableName }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      Here you can insert a loader
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Test',
    data() {
        return {
            variableName: null,
        };
    },
    computed() {
        shouldDisplay() {
            return this.variableName !== null;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.variableName = 'yes';
    },
};
</script>
```

In this way it's easier to show a loader only if the data is not ready (using `v-else`).

In this particular case `v-if="variableName"` would work as well, but there can be more complicated scenarios.

Comment: That works for after the page script is loaded and vue is mounted. This is also a pre-compiled component. The OP was referring to a page that is compiled at runtime, which the browser loads the page first. And if your script is slow to load, then for a brief moment you see the vue syntax.