# is it possible to use directive intercepting vue from render the template

Tags: vue.js, render, vue-directives

Is it possible to use directive preventing vue from render the template?

For example

```
<div v-prevent-render>{{ variable }}</div>
```

will show `{{ variable }}`,
but not the value of `variable`

---update---

Actually, I was prepared to do some operations before render, not just to show the original text... When things done, I will use $mount or render.

So maybe what I need is kind of a render interceptor...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`v-pre`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre) for that:

```
<div v-pre>{{ variable }}</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/5bnv7v28/

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know this existed. I actually spent 20 min trying to make a directive for this

Comment: Actually, I was prepared to do some operations before render, not just to show the original text...

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262007/hiding-vue-js-template-before-it-is-rendered/42262375#42262375

Comment: For example, I dont have a variable alias in data, but I'd like to create one before render

Comment: @craig_h Thanks but that's not my needed