# How to avoid having django template display before VueJS render

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, fetch, lifecycle

I have a Django template that I'm trying to render with VueJs using CDN.
The problem is when the page is loaded, i see the raw code of Django with the delimiters before it get rendered with VueJS. It takes less that a sec.

I have an API call (using Fetch) that retrieve some data before displaying them and I put that in mounted() function. The delay is almost 0.6sec and we can see Django render before vuejs render the page.

Then I change mounted() to `beforeMount()`. I now see the Django render from time to time but it's much better because often, vue render comes first.

Is there a better way to solve this?  I'm using CDN, and I didn't want to get into server-side rendering for this project.

Comment: Please, show what exactly you mean. For undesirable markup output, cloaking can be used (`body` or some element is output with CSS class that has `display:none`, then a class is removed in JS), but the primary problem is that server side code shouldn't leak outside server app at all, it's unsafe

Comment: Thanks Estus, actually i just found the answer going through the doc and also here back on stackOver
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262007/hiding-vue-js-template-before-it-is-rendered

Comment: I see, so you mean Vue delimiters. Then it's ok, v-cloak it is.

Answer (score 3):

The directive v-cloak solve it.

```
<div id="#app">
    <div v-cloak>
       [[ message ]]  // Vue delimiters for django.
    </div>
</div>
```

with the style

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

Juste make sure to add the directive inside of the main #app div

More to it here
[Hiding vue.js template before it is rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262007/hiding-vue-js-template-before-it-is-rendered)