# Conditionally rendering a modal based on Vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I want to conditionally show my authentication modal based on whether a token exists in my Vuex store. It's very straightforward and I have this working almost 100%.

The part I've been spinning my wheels on is that when the token is present, I get a brief flash of the auth modal before the rest of the content is rendered. Ideally, the modal shouldn't render at all because `!token` is false.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// layouts/default
<template>
  <div v-if="!loading">
    <Nav :token="token"/>
    <div class="ui container" v-if="token">
      <nuxt/>
    </div>
    <Auth :open="!token"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import Auth from "@/components/Auth";
import Nav from "@/components/Nav";
export default {
  computed: mapState({
    token: state => state.auth.token,
    loading: state => state.auth === "loading"
  }),
  components: {
    Nav,
    Auth
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("auth/checkLocalAuth");
  }
};
</script>
```

```
// store/auth.js

const store = require("store");

export const state = {
  token: store.get("userToken") || "",
  status: "loading"
};
export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated: state => state.token,
  authStatus: state => state.status
};
export const mutations = {
  // ..
  success: (state, token) => {
    state.status = "success";
    state.token = token;
  },
  //...
};

export const actions = {
  checkLocalAuth: ({ commit }) => {
    const token = store.get("userToken") || "";
    commit("success", token);
  },
  //...
...
```

```
// components/Auth.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <sui-modal v-model="open">
    //...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    open: {
      default: false
    }
  },
  //...
```

If I explicitly set `<Auth :open="false" />`, I do not get the modal flash.

Comment: Seems like there should be a `v-if` on the `Auth` component.  Nothing is telling it not to render at the moment, even if you don't see anything at certain times.  `<Auth v-if="!token" :open="!token"/>`

Comment: @Dan see my comment to Andrei below please. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Still flashing or something else?  Next I would try `v-if="open"` on the outer `div` in the `Auth` template

Comment: Also [`v-cloak`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870926/v-cloak-does-not-work-in-vue-js)

Comment: Still flashing. If I clear caches with each render, it's not perceptible 100% of the time. Maybe some odd race condition. It's just strange that a `true` condition is never passed to the v-if or :open param, and the Auth modal defaults to 'false', so…

Answer (score 1):

If `token = ""`, then `!token` is not `false`, but `true`. So this might be causing the issue.

Comment: Assuming the default token value is "", this should work: `<Auth v-if="token === ''" :open="token === ''"/>`, but it doesn't. But `<Auth v-if="token === ''" :open="false"/>` works.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The issue was ssr related. Once I disabled ssr it's fine.

It's not 100% the right solution if we do want ssr, but its not a requirement for now. Will address if it becomes one!